# Ruby on Rails behind nginx on Google Cloud Run fails to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm having a weird problem deploying Ruby on Rails to Google Cloud Run. I made a main container (nginx) that works on the default Cloud Run PORT (8080) and 2 sidecars (rails on port 3000 and Next.js on port 3001). Nginx and Next.js seem to work perfectly well, but Rails fails to even start. No logs, even though I set logs to :debug and made sure to direct them to STDOUT. Just `Container called exit(0)` in Cloud Run logs and the whole container restarts.

The weird thing is that once I change the nginx container to whatever and set the Rails server to port 8080, it magically starts the server and I can see all the logs.

What could lead to such weird behavior and how can I make rails work with this setup?

---

Nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    error_log /dev/stderr;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    server {
        listen 8080; 
        server_name _;
        gzip on;

        # Proxy to Rails server for all other paths
        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # Proxy to Next.js server for paths starting with /frontend
        location /frontend {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /_next {
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3001/_next";
        }

        # return plain text "hello" for testing purposes
        location /hello {
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 'hello';
        }
    }
}
```

How I start rails in the sidecar:

```
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]
```

How I start nginx:

```
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

UPD: I think the issue is with the fact that the main container (nginx) gets started superfast and Cloud Run quickly performs health check and rolls out and redirects all the traffic to the new revision. Rails server takes some time to start and rolling out the revision somehow breaks the server process.

I added 60s sleep and it works now:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "sleep 60 && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

This feels like a dirty workaround, so some additional rails health check before starting nginx is required.

Comment: Are you using always on instances or on demand. Something to keep in mind is if your cloud run instance isn't serving traffic then it will terminate, so what could be happening is that your container starts, see's there's no traffic and then terminates. If the cloud run health check is getting a 2XX response then it assumes the container is working and completes the rollout.